# Webmin/Postfix+Dovecot - I can send e-mails, but not receive them

Tags: postfix, dovecot

OK, so I have a server with Virtual Domains installed through Webmin/Virtualmin, all DNS settings configured, including the mail.domain.com. one, and I can send e-mails.

However, I cannot receive them. I check /var/log/maillog and it's always empty.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you telnet to your mailserver to port 25 (telnet [my.host.com] 25? Do you receive any answer?

Comment: Yes, http://i.imgur.com/07JupCK.png

Comment: Check "dig -t mx mydomain.com", it should report your mailserver host and IP address

Comment: Also post the output of "netstat -tulpn | grep 25"

Comment: dig -t mx mydomain.com = http://i.imgur.com/VDmNqtu.png
netstat -tulpn | grep 25 = http://i.imgur.com/0uuYtS1.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some problems in the domain resolution of the A record of **mail.wenoo.net**. Please check:

```
$ nslookup mail.wenoo.net
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 8.8.8.8, trying next server
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

and:

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 -t a mail.wenoo.net

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @8.8.8.8 -t a mail.wenoo.net
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 28123
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mail.wenoo.net.            IN  A

;; Query time: 84 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Mon Oct 12 07:50:46 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 32
```

Try to remove the record and add it again on your DNS configuration panel.

And remove the double "mail.wenoo.net" MX record:

```
wenoo.net.      3599    IN  MX  10 mail.wenoo.net.
wenoo.net.      3599    IN  MX  0 mail.wenoo.net.
```

One is enough  and having two MX records on the same server makes non sense.

Comment: Oh, my. Thank you so much!
All I needed to do was remove the MX record from Mail Server and somehow, it worked instantly. I can't thank you enough!